# XInclude not working properly on command line Saxon, but does work with oXygen

Tags: xml, saxon, oxygenxml, xinclude

I have some XML files transcribing manuscripts that draw from a shared description of the book those manuscripts are in. It's formatted in my XML via three include statements that are laid out as follows:

```
<xi:include href="../Witness_Descriptions/Trinity_R_3_20.xml" xpointer="publication" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
<xi:include href="../Witness_Descriptions/Trinity_R_3_20.xml" xpointer="Trinity_R_3_20" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
<xi:include href="../Witness_Descriptions/Minor_Poems_Vol_II.xml" xpointer="MacCracken" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
```

When I run the xslt within oXygen to transform this into html (using oXygen's built-in Saxon-PE 10.6 Transformer) it works fine. However, I need to have the ability to generate comparisons between the whole corpus of documents, which I use a saxon-he 9 transformer for with the following command line:

```
java -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -t -xi -q:test.xq -o:1698815174.72894737321461.xml line=l.1 zone=EETS.ME.I marginalia=text collection=/home/matrygg/minorworksoflydgate.net/XML/Mumming_Eltham
```

Which collects the xml files from a particular directory using the following two lines and $collection as an externally declared variable:

```
let $collection:=concat($collection, '?select=*.xml')
let $q:=collection($collection)
```

If I don't have any includes on the XML files in the Mumming_Eltham directory this works fine and does what I expect. If I do -- as I have started to do as mentioned above -- I get the following error:

```
Warning: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
  file:/home/matrygg/minorworksoflydgate.net/XML/Mumming_Eltham/Trinity_College_R_3_20_Mumming_Eltham.xml; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 142; Include operation failed, reverting to fallback. Resource error reading file as XML (href='../Witness_Descriptions/Trinity_R_3_20.xml'). Reason: XPointer resolution unsuccessful.
Error on line 22 column 142 of Trinity_College_R_3_20_Mumming_Eltham.xml:
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: An include with href
  '../Witness_Descriptions/Trinity_R_3_20.xml'failed, and no fallback element was found.
Query failed with dynamic error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/USERNAME/minorworksoflydgate.net/XML/Mumming_Eltham/Trinity_College_R_3_20_Mumming_Eltham.xml; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 142; An include with href '../Witness_Descriptions/Trinity_R_3_20.xml'failed, and no fallback element was found.
```

It's obvious to me that the issue is that it's not handling relative paths, but I can't find any examples of how to resolve this within the command line interface or the xml, only via fn:resolve-uri in xsl. Is there a way to do this at the command line, or do I have to put in absolute URI's for everything I might want to include?  I've checked and the files exist in the location expected and should have permissions to allow them to be parsed.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any input file to the XQuery, or is there one? How/where in your XQuery do you read in files, can you show the relevant code and explain a bit in as far the XQuery code and the input files are in different folders/directories?

Comment: It's being fed in via an external variable, referenced in the command line as collection Within the xquery I have .the following lines to grab the various .xml files in the directory and then grab the appropriate bits from all of them:

let $collection:=concat($collection, '?select=*.xml')
let $q:=collection($collection)

I can include the contents of the whole .xq file for you guys, but I've never quite hit the fine line between providing too little and too much information.  Let me know if it would help and I'll be happy to add it.  I will edit the post above to include this information

Answer (score 0):

If the base URI of the document containing the `xi:include` element is correct, then this should work. You haven't shown how this document is read. Presumably it's something to do with the `collection` parameter to your query, but beyond that, we're guessing.

The other factor that can be relevant here is that it's not actually Saxon that is doing the XInclude processing; it's the XML parser which Saxon invokes. It looks as if XInclude processing has been successfully enabled on the XML parser, so that's half of the battle. The other half is getting the base URI right.

Comment: Sorry about not mentioning how it's read.  As I mentioned in the comment above I sometimes have a hard time hitting the sweet spot between too little and too much information if I ask questions on here.

It's parsing -- I can get results if I don't include the -xi on the command line, but I obviously don't get the elements I'm taking out of the included files.  So my thinking is that it's either that it doesn't like the uris or it doesn't like the xpointer.  But since it does work within oXygen I'm thinking it's more likely the former than the latter.

Comment: Doing a long horizontal scroll, I see that it's actually complaining about the `xpointer` value. I'm afraid I'm out of my depth there, I suspect there may be differences between `XInclude` processors as to how the attribute is handled, so you may well find that Oxygen is using a different `XInclude` processor than the Xerces one which Saxon enables.

Answer (score 0):

After hunting around online some more I found this thread on here that deals with a similar issue but with .xslt:

[How to resolve XInclude instructions in a XML file from command line with XSLT 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324659/how-to-resolve-xinclude-instructions-in-a-xml-file-from-command-line-with-xslt-3?rq=1)

I went ahead and updated the version of Saxon I'm using, added the patch oXygen pointed Martine Hinze to (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oxygenxml/oxygen-patched-xerces/25.1.0.2) and ran my command line with the following command:

```
java -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -cp 'oxygen-patched-xerces-25.1.0.2.jar:saxon-he-12.3.jar' net.sf.saxon.Query -t -xi -q:test.xq -o:1698982391.97692339769168.xml line=l.1 zone=EETS.ME.H.1 marginalia=header collection=file:/home/USERNAME/minorworksoflydgate.net/XML/Mumming_Eltham
```

This resolved things without a hitch. So should someone come long with similar problems, the solution is to get the patch oXygen uses for the Xerces parser.